# How to draw UIBezierPath on CALayer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

Currently I do it like this:

```
    for (_, values) in data {

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: leftOffset, y: bottomOffset - values.first! * scale))

        for index in 1..<values.count {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: leftOffset + widthForMonth * CGFloat(index), y: bottomOffset - values[index] * scale))
        }

        colors[currentIndex].set()
        UIColor.clear.setFill()
        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.stroke()

        layer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        currentIndex += 1
    }
```

but the result is unexpected:

[image]

Before I setup a `CALayer` it was like this:

[image]

What is wrong here? I really need this on CALayer, because I need hide or unhide it at any time later.

Comment: I'm unclear what you were expecting. Were you looking to "fill in" the bottom part of the graph? If so, check into where you are setting a closePath - you may need to in **every** X axis iteration.

Comment: to close the Path should I back to start through every middle point?:) why I do not need to do this if I do not use `CALayer`?

Comment: You should replace `UIColor.clear.setFill()` by `path.fillColor = nil`, and don't close the path.

Comment: Where is this code located? You should not be drawing except in a situation where there is an active drawing context (usually inside a view's `drawRect()`, or a layer's `draw(in:)` or `display()` methods.) It doesn't make sense to both stroke your path AND add add a shape layer as a sublayer of the view's layer.

Comment: there is no property `fillColor`...

Comment: Everything is inside `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

Comment: You didn't say if you are trying to **copy** the second (unfilled) image or something else. If you are simply trying to copy the image,  you'll have some issues with CAShapeLayer, as you have different colored lines that intersect each other towards the end. You might be better off just drawing the paths in a CGContext.

Comment: no, I do not copy any image at all... All I do is draw some lines and that is all...

Comment: @dfd, I made things working with your idea, I iterated over all X values back.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Could you please post the solution for the above ?